# Testing play framework controller witch uses custom action

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito, scalatest

I want to unit-test a controller method and to do that I need to mock out every dependency.

This is my controller:

```
class InvoiceController @Inject() (
    cc: ControllerComponents,
    authAction: AuthAction,
    dao: InvoicerDao
) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def saveInvoice: Action[AnyContent] = authAction { implicit userRequest =>
    Ok("ok")
  }
}
```

I made a custom action with ActionBuilder and it is injected in the constructor. I use this action to Authenticate users.

My unit test looks like this:

```
class InvoiceControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {

  val authMock: AuthAction = mock[AuthAction]
  val daoMock: InvoicerDao = mock[InvoicerDao]

  val underTest: InvoiceController = new InvoiceController(
    Helpers.stubControllerComponents(),
    authMock,
    daoMock
  )

  "InvoiceController" should {
    "should save invoice" in {
      val body =
        Source.fromResource("InvoiceControllerSaveInvoice.json").mkString.trim

      val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/saveInvoice")
        .withJsonBody(Json.toJson(body))

      val userResult = Future {
        Ok("Authorized.")
      }
      when(authMock.invokeBlock(any, any)).thenReturn(userResult)

      val result: Future[Result] = underTest.saveInvoice.apply(
        request
      )

      status(result) mustBe 200
    }
  }
}
```

After running the test I get NullPointerException.

I'm using mockito and scala test plus.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

If you know a better way to test this, please help.

Thank you!

Comment: You already posted this question few days ago. Can you share the error with stack trace?

Comment: Sure: java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at controllers.InvoiceControllerSpec.$anonfun$new$4(InvoiceControllerSpec.scala:51)
 at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
 at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
 at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
 at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)

Comment: at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
 at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$3.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1075)
 at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
 at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
 at org.scalatest.WordSpec.withFixture(WordSpec.scala:1881)
 at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1073)
 at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1085)
 at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:286)
 at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.runTest(WordSpecLike.scala:1085)

Comment: ........ org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1011)
 at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
 at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)

Comment: Update your original post and tell us to which line of your code it match to, like line 51: where is it in your code?